# Как сделать такой незаконченный border?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать `border`, который размещается не по всей высоте блока?

Кроме как реализовать пустым `div` с левым и правым `border` и с `z-index` меньше, чем у контента, ничего лучшего я не придумал?
Но, похоже, это не так делается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужно добавить сюда код, что Вы уже сделали

Comment: Ссылку на сайт можно?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй использовать градиент

```
.top-to-bottom {
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(black), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))) 1 100%;
    -webkit-border-image: 
      -webkit-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    -moz-border-image:
      -moz-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;    
    -o-border-image:
      -o-linear-gradient(black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
    border-image:
      linear-gradient(to bottom, black, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)) 1 100%;
}
```